# How do I get the index of the largest element adjacent to the greatest element in a list

Tags: python, list

So I have `stock = [5,6,8,4,8,3,6,4]`. I want to get the index of the greatest element adjacent to the 1st occurrence of the greatest element, 8. So what I want to get will be 6 with index 1. I have tried using this code.

```py
closest = min(range(len(stock)), key=lambda i: abs(stock[i]-max(stock)))
```

but it just returns the max element.

Comment: So you want to find the 1st occurence of the highest element, then, then return the index of its highest neighbor?

Comment: yes rhats correct

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, the most interesting input would look like `[1,5,8,4,8,7,6,4]`. I.e. we need to return the index of the `5` since it's a second maximum closest to the first occurrence of the maximum. If so, then the algorithm would look as follows:

```
find two leftmost and absolute maximums m1 and m2
if m1 == m2 then the target is in either of two subarrays:
    [0, pos(m1))
    [pos(m1) + 1, pos(m2))
otherwise, the target is in either of the following subarrays:
    [0, pos(m1))
    [pos(m1) + 1, len(arr))
```

We can find *k* max elements in an array in a close to linear time using the [*binary heap*](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html). So, I think I got a linear solution for you:

```
import heapq

def nlargest_with_pos(n, arr):
    assert len(arr) >= n
    largest = heapq.nlargest(n, ((it[1], -it[0]) for it in enumerate(arr)))
    return [(it[0], -it[1]) for it in largest]

def find_x(arr):
    assert len(arr) > 1

    first_max, second_max = nlargest_with_pos(2, arr)
    if len(arr) == 2:
        return second_max[1]

    left_range = (0, first_max[1])

    if second_max[0] == first_max[0]:
        right_range = (first_max[1] + 1, second_max[1])
    else:
        right_range = (first_max[1] + 1, len(arr))

    left_hand = arr[left_range[0]:left_range[1]]
    right_hand = arr[right_range[0]:right_range[1]]

    if not left_hand:
        return nlargest_with_pos(1, right_hand)[0][1]
    if not right_hand:
        return nlargest_with_pos(1, left_hand)[0][1]

    left_second_max = nlargest_with_pos(1, left_hand)[0]
    right_second_max = nlargest_with_pos(1, right_hand)[0]

    if left_second_max[0] >= right_second_max[0]:
        return left_second_max[1]
    else:
        return right_second_max[1]

print(find_x([1,5,8,4,8,7,6,4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very pretty, but it will cater for all possible scenarios, i.e.  your list, max value a the start or the end, two or one value list.

Code is:

```
def highest_neighbour(stock):
    if stock:
        x = stock.index(max(stock))
        if x - 1 >= 0:
            if x + 1 < len(stock):
                if stock[x + 1] > stock[x - 1]:
                    return x + 1
            return x - 1
        elif x + 1 < len(stock):
            return x + 1
        else:
            return -1
```

I've set it to return -1 if the list only has one entry.

Output is:

```
highest_neighbour([5,6,8,4,8,3,6,4]) # ->  1
highest_neighbour([5,6,8,4,8,3,6,9]) # ->  6
highest_neighbour([9,6,8,4,8,3,6,4]) # ->  1
highest_neighbour([3,5])             # ->  0
highest_neighbour([8])               # -> -1
highest_neighbour([])                # -> None
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
stock = [5,6,8,7,8,3,6,4]

if stock.index(max(stock)) == len(stock)-1:
    print(len(stock)-2)
elif not stock.index(max(stock)):
    print(1)
elif stock[stock.index(max(stock))-1] > stock[stock.index(max(stock))+1]:
    print(stock.index(max(stock))-1)
else:
    print(stock.index(max(stock))+1)
```

Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant but this should work nonetheless:

```
stock.index(max(stock[stock.index(max(stock)) - 1], stock[(stock.index(max(stock)) + 1) % len(stock)]))
```

You'll have to add handling if there's a chance you see a list with less than three values

Comment: What if maximum value is at either end of `stock`?  Or if the "second max" appears elsewhere?

Comment: Edited to handle highest value at the end of the list. It treats the first and last elements in the list as neighbors. This can be fixed pretty easily if not desired.

Comment: This returns the wrong value for a list like `[5,6,8,4,8,3,6,9]` as it returns the index of the first 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
def max_neighbor_index(l: list):
    max_number = max(l)
    max_number_indexes = [x for x in range(0, len(l)) if l[x] == max_number]
    result = []
    for number_index in max_number_indexes:
        if number_index == 0:
            result.append(1)
        elif number_index == len(l) - 1:
            result.append(len(l) - 2)
        else:
            result.append(l.index(max([l[number_index - 1], l[number_index + 1]])))
    max_neighbor = max([l[x] for x in result])
    return [x for x in result if l[x] == max_neighbor][0]


stock = [5, 6, 8, 4, 8, 3, 6, 4]
print(max_neighbor_index(stock))
```

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

This prints index of highest element that's next to the first occurrence of maximum value in list `stock`:

```
stock = [1,5,8,4,8,7,6,4]

idx_max = stock.index(max(stock))
print(max([i for i in [idx_max-1, idx_max+1] if -1 < i < len(stock)], key=lambda k: stock[k]))
```

Prints:

```
1
```

---

Test cases:

```
stock = [8,3,8,4,8,3,6,4]   # 1
stock = [1,3,1,3,8,5,6,4]   # 5
stock = [1,3,1,4,1,3,6,8]   # 6
stock = [1,5,8,4,8,7,6,4]   # 1
```

Comment: I think it fails on `[1,5,8,4,8,7,6,4]`

Comment: @IvanVelichko Yep, OP wants indexes. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
def get_max_neighbour(l):
    _max = max(l)
    excl = (-1, len(l))
    neighbour = max(
        (
            (l[j], j)
            for i in range(excl[-1])
            for j in (i-1, i+1)
            if l[i] == _max and j not in excl
        ),
        key=lambda x: x[0]
    )
    return neighbour[1]
```

Result:

```
1
```

The nice thing about this is you can return both the value and index if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
stock = [5,6,8,4,8,3,6,4]
idx = 1
tmp,nxt = stock[0:2]
for i in range(1, len(stock)):
    buf = stock[i-1] if i == len(stock)-1 else max(stock[i-1], stock[i+1])
    if tmp < stock[i] or (tmp == stock[i] and nxt < buf): 
        idx = stock.index(buf, i-1)
        nxt = stock[idx]
        tmp = stock[i]
print('greatest next to greatest', nxt, 'at', idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to this puzzle.  I'd say it is most similar to the solution of @DavidBuck, in that `[8]` -> `-1` and `[]` -> `None`, but has four fewer exit points:

```
from math import inf

def index_of_max_neighbor_of_max(array):
    if not array:
        return None

    index = array.index(max(array))
    a = array[index - 1] if index - 1 >= 0 else -inf
    b = array[index + 1] if index + 1 < len(array) else -inf
    return index + (b > a) * 2 - 1
```

And my test code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    iomnom = index_of_max_neighbor_of_max

    print(iomnom([5, 6, 8, 4, 8, 3, 6, 4]))  # 1
    print(iomnom([5, 6, 8, 4, 8, 3, 6, 9]))  # 6
    print(iomnom([5, 3]))  # 1
    print(iomnom([3, 5]))  # 0
    print(iomnom([8]))  # -1
    print(iomnom([]))  # None
    print(iomnom([5, 6, 8, 7, 8, 3, 6, 4]))  # 3
    print(iomnom([5, 6, 8, 4, 8, 3, 6, 9]))  # 6
    print(iomnom([5, 4, 8, 6, 8, 3, 6, 4]))  # 3
```